# How to assign fields to class that implements an interaface, using an interface as input?

Tags: c#

Say I have a class that implements interface IInterfaceOne and IInterfaceTwo.

Those interfaces have different properties, which I don't want to set individually.

Now I have a class that looks something like this:

```
public class SomeClass : IInterfaceOne, IInterfaceTwo 
{
    // From IInterfaceOne
    public Field1 { get; set; }
    public Field2 { get; set; }

    // From IInterfaceTwo
    public Field3 { get; set; }
    public Field4 { get; set; }
}
```

Say I have an instance of 'SomeClass' in 'SomeOtherClass' like so and I wanted to assign values to 'SomeClass' using a parameter that implements 'IInterfaceOne'

```
public class SomeOtherClass
{
    private SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();

    public void DoSomething(IInterfaceOne someParameter)
    {
        // Is there a way to say
        // someClass = someParameter
        // and copy the values from 'someParameter' to 'someClass' 
        // with out creating a new instance of 'someClass'?
    }
}
```

I get that I can make a method to assign these individually and just call that each time, but I am wondering if there is a better, quicker or a cleaner way to do this (such as `someClass = (SomeClass)someParameter`, without destroying the original instance of 'someClass').

Comment: Set all the fields manually or use an Automapper.

Comment: Perhaps a Visual Studio extension that examines the classes and writes mapping code? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=54748ff9-45fc-43c2-8ec5-cf7912bc3b84.mappinggenerator